# Openlayers3 Marker/icon Clustering in WebGL

Tags: openlayers, markers

I try to create a webGL-based icon-Clustering with an array of self-hosted images. My approach was to combine the iconSprites-WebGL-Example with ol.clusterSource. The ClusterLayer shoes up, but it is only displayed as pointCoordinates without the images. If i only render the main vectorLayer, all images are there, but (of course) not clustered. Somehow i can´t access the features from the vectorLayer inside the clusterLayer. Does anybody have an idea, what i´m doing wrong (js is attached)

```
var i;
var iconCount = 1001;
var icons = new Array(iconCount);

for (i = 0; i < iconCount; ++i) {

icons[i] = new ol.style.Icon({
  opacity: 1,
  size: [100, 100],
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  src: 'data/images_' + i + '.jpg'
});
}

var featureCount = 1000;

var features = new Array(featureCount);
var feature, geometry;
var e = 25000000;

for (i = 0; i < featureCount; ++i) {
  geometry = new ol.geom.Point(
  [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e]);

  feature = new ol.Feature(geometry);
  feature.setStyle(
  new ol.style.Style({
    image: icons[i % (iconCount - 1)]
  })
  );
  features[i] = feature;
}

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features
});
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

// ********************** CLUSTERING ********************************

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: 40,
    source: vectorSource
});

var clusterLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: clusterSource
});


var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [clusterLayer],
  renderer: 'webgl',
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 5
  })
});
```